# Get total number of hours from a Pandas Timedelta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

How can I get the total number of hours in a Pandas timedelta?

For example:

```
>>> td = pd.Timedelta('1 days 2 hours')
>>> td.get_total_hours()
26
```

Note: as per the documentation, the `.hours` attribute will return the hours *component*:

```
>>> td.hours
2
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Just find out how many `timedelta`s of 1 hour fit into it:

```
import numpy as np

>> td / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
26.0
```

Comment: I prefer `pd.Timedelta(hours=1)` since OP is already using pandas.

Comment: Wondering why there is no Timedelta.hours property.

Answer (score 31):

Just try to show why pandas returns 2 hours.

```
import pandas as pd

td = pd.Timedelta('1 days 2 hours')

td.components

Out[45]: Components(days=1, hours=2, minutes=0, seconds=0, milliseconds=0, microseconds=0, nanoseconds=0)

td / pd.Timedelta('1 hour')

Out[46]: 26.0
```

Answer (score 24):

I am getting the time delta in seconds and dividing it by 3600 to get hours

`round(td.total_seconds() / 3600)` .

When I tested in jupyter notebook this approach works faster

```
%timeit td / np.timedelta64(1, 'h') 
The slowest run took 19.10 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.58 µs per loop

%timeit round(td.total_seconds() / 3600)
The slowest run took 18.08 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 401 ns per loop
```