# Date difference in hours (Excel data import)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp

I need to calculate hour difference between two dates (format: year-month-dayTHH:MM:SS  I could also potentially transform data format to (format: year-month-day HH:MM:SS) from huge excel file. What is the most efficient way to do it in Python? I have tried to use Datatime/Time object (TypeError: expected string or buffer), Timestamp (ValueError) and DataFrame (does not give hour result).

Excel File:

```
Order_Date             Received_Customer   Column3
2000-10-06T13:00:58    2000-11-06T13:00:58    1
2000-10-21T15:40:15    2000-12-27T10:09:29    2
2000-10-23T10:09:29    2000-10-26T10:09:29    3
.....                  ....
```

**Datatime/Time object code** (TypeError: expected string or buffer):

```
import pandas as pd
import time as t

data=pd.read_excel('/path/file.xlsx')

s1 = (data,['Order_Date'])
s2 = (data,['Received_Customer'])

s1Time = t.strptime(s1, "%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S")
s2Time = t.strptime(s2, "%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S")

deltaInHours = (t.mktime(s2Time) - t.mktime(s1Time))

print deltaInHours, "hours"
```

**Timestamp (ValueError) code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

data=pd.read_excel('/path/file.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Order_Date','Received_Customer'])
df.to = [pd.Timestamp('Order_Date')]
df.fr = [pd.Timestamp('Received_Customer')]
(df.fr-df.to).astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

**DataFrame (does not return the desired result)**

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_excel('/path/file.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Order_Date','Received_Customer'])

df['Order_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order_Date'])
df['Received_Customer'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Received_Customer'])

answer = df.dropna()['Order_Date'] - df.dropna()['Received_Customer']

answer.astype('timedelta64[h]')

print(answer)
```

Output:

```
0   24 days 16:38:07
1    0 days 00:00:00
2   20 days 12:39:52
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Should be something like this:

```
0   592 hour
1   0   hour
2   492 hour
```

Is there another way to convert `timedelta64[ns]` into **hours** than `answer.astype('timedelta64[h]')`?

Comment: You've asked this question some minutes ago, remember... That is not the way it wors here, asking a question, delete it ad ask it again!

Comment: @linusg did not mean to delete it, by accident!

Answer (score 1):

For each of your solutions you mixed up datatypes and methods. Whereas I do not find the time to explicitly explain your mistakes, yet i want to help you by providing a (probably non optimal) solution.
I built the solution out of your previous tries and I combined it with knowledge from other questions such as:

[Convert a timedelta to days, hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes)

[Get total number of hours from a Pandas Timedelta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283001/get-total-number-of-hours-from-a-pandas-timedelta)

Note that i used Python 3. I hope that my solution guides your way. My solution is this one:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import  datetime
import numpy as np

d = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\nrieble\\Desktop\\check.xlsx',header=0)

start = [pd.to_datetime(e) for e in data['Order_Date'] if len(str(e))>4]
end = [pd.to_datetime(e) for e in data['Received_Customer'] if len(str(e))>4]

delta = np.asarray(s2Time)-np.asarray(s1Time)
deltainhours = [e/np.timedelta64(1, 'h') for e in delta]

print (deltainhours, "hours")
```